# Customer with multiple addresses, can have only one primary address

Tags: django, django-models

I created an app 'customerbin' inside my Django install. I need to create/edit/delete customers who can have multiple addresses where only one address can be primary. If a customer is deleted, all the addresses that belong to that customer need to be deleted as well. If a new customer is created we can't pick an address from another customer.

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models

class Address(models.Model):
    street = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    number = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    postal = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_primary = models.BooleanField(null=False)
    geo_lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=22, decimal_places=16, blank=True, null=True)
    geo_lon = models.DecimalField(max_digits=22, decimal_places=16, blank=True, null=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    vat = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**admin.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from . import models

# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(models.Customer)
admin.site.register(models.Address)
```

How can I make it so that:

- An address is exclusively linked to one customer?
- All addresses are deleted when I delete a customer?
- Only one address is primary for a customer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a Foreign Key from `Customer` to `Address` you should have a Foreign Key from `Address` to `Customer`. To ensure that only one primary address exists for a user use a [`UniqueConstraint` [Django-docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint) with a `condition`:

```
from django.db.models import Q


class Address(models.Model):
    street = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    number = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    postal = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_primary = models.BooleanField(null=False)
    geo_lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=22, decimal_places=16, blank=True, null=True)
    geo_lon = models.DecimalField(max_digits=22, decimal_places=16, blank=True, null=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    # Here ↓
    customer = models.ForeignKey("Customer", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="addresses")
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.is_primary:
            self.__class__._default_manager.filter(customer=self.customer, is_primary=True).update(is_primary=False)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['customer'],
                condition=Q(is_primary=True),
                name='unique_primary_per_customer'
            )
        ]


class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    vat = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    
    # Remove address from here
```

Here `on_delete=models.CASCADE` would cause an address to be deleted if the related customer is deleted.

Comment: This seems to do what I expect it to do, except when I edit an address and make a non-primary address primary. Then it throws an error: 'UNIQUE constraint failed: customerbin_address.customer_id'

Comment: @andyderuyter You need to handle that case. I have edited my answer and overriden the `save` method of the model to do that (Will set all other addresses of the customer as not the primary address). Note that this has some caveats though, for example `bulk_create` or `bulk_update` would not use the `save` method hence would give you the error you just got (if a customer already has a primary address).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're linking the two models incorrectly. From the code above, when the corresponding address is deleted the user gets deleted which is not what you want. So, here is my suggestion. Add a foreign key in the `Address` model to the `Customer` model with `on_delete=models.CASCADE` also add a boolean field `is_primary` in the `Address` model with a default value to `False`. And you can handle the logic for only-one-primary-address in the `clean` method of the `Address` model where you can check if there is already a primary address for the user whose address is being added. If yes, create a validation error. If not, continue as usual. If this explanation is not enough, I can help you with the code too.